# I'd want to exclude current post from related post

Tags: posts

I have a problem with my blog, I put 12 posts and related post show always current post (and others), how can I fix that ? thanks for support

```
<div style='clear:both'/>  

<div id='related-posts'>

        <b:if cond='data:post.labels'>
          <b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
            <b:if cond='data:label.isLast == &quot;true&quot;'>
              <data:label.name/>
            </b:if>
          </b:loop>
        </b:if>
      </div>
 <div style='clear:both'/>    
<div class='post-pager' id='post-pager'>
    <b:if cond='data:newerPageUrl'>
      <span id='blog-pager-newer-link'>
      <a class='blog-pager-newer-link' expr:href='data:newerPageUrl' expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_blog-pager-newer-link&quot;' expr:title='data:newerPageTitle'/>
      </span>
    </b:if>
```

Comment: The code you posted does not help. Can you post the code you use to query the related posts?

Comment: How can I find it ? If I search for related-posts I find this code and this: 

related-posts {background: #fff;padding: 0 0 10px;}h4.related-title {font-size.....

Comment: I think you are a blogspot.com user.

Comment: @gaurav Yes, there's a way to fix it ?